# PlayFramework with Morphia?

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, nonblocking, morphia

`PlayFramework` is a `NonBlockingIO` application architecture whereas `Morphia` (driver for `MongoDB`) is not a non blocking `IO`. If I am not wrong then `playframeworks` `MVC` architecture works in following way:

- `Controllers returns the Promise and call the Dao methods`(So far it's Performing Non Blocking IO).
- Dao will perform the `IO` operations in DB using `Morphia` driver.
- Morphia is not based on `NonBlocking IO`.

Every-time Morphia will make a `Asynchronous` request to `MongoDB` server and for every request each `callback` will be there

Should we use `Morphia` with `PlayFramework`? It's sounds like that our `controllers` are based on `NonBlocking IO` but internally they are just `Blocking IO`.

Comment: If I properly understood you, you want to know how to mix a async/non-blocking framework (play) with a sync/blocking framework (morphia). Is that right? If so, you should probably take a look at [how slick approaches this problem](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/database.html#database-thread-pool).